# IIS redirection to external web site

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-modules

Is it possible to create local web site in local IIS with some domain, for example. dummy-website

and when locally enter that domain to be redirected to some other web site in internet, note that after redirection url need to stay dummy-website, content of web site from internet needs to be displayed in requested local domain.

Tnx

Answer (score 0):

yes there is:

In IIS Manager, expand the local computer, right-click the Web site or directory you want to redirect, and click Properties.

Click the Home Directory, Virtual Directory, or Directory tab.

Under The content for this source should come from, click A redirection to a URL.

In the Redirect to box, type the URL of the destination directory or Web site. For example, to redirect all requests for files in the Catalog directory to the NewCatalog directory, type /NewCatalog.

and there you go! 
Hope this helps.